# Cannot authorize with my own account at https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/

Tags: oauth

After clicking on "authorize using your own account" and logged in with my work account (I'm a Microsoft employee, so I meant my Microsoft email), I got the error "OAuth Sandbox needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it."

I have contacted Microsoft IT, but they told me to contact the app owner here. Here is the details:

Request Id: 6462a541-01d1-4899-84f9-6b77c3423200 
Correlation Id: 9e8d35bd-f719-4422-ab97-941680b32b58 
Timestamp: 2019-01-25T00:40:25Z 
Message: AADSTS900941: An administrator of Microsoft has set a policy that prevents you from granting OAuth Sandbox the permissions it is requesting. Contact an administrator of Microsoft who can grant permissions to this application on your behalf. 
Advanced diagnostics: Disable 
If you plan on getting support for an issue, turn this on and try to reproduce the error. This will collect additional information that will help troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Microsoft IT is asking you to reach out to the app owner on stackoverflow.microsoft.com, not on the public stackoverflow site. You should delete this message.

You need to find the owner of that page, presumably the outlook team, and have them request Microsoft IT allow their AAD AppId 32613fc5-e7ac-4894-ac94-fbc39c9f3e4a.